# Change the icon of the button but does not want to set the location of the image

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

I want to change the image of the button (which I know how to do it) . Is there any other way of adding the image without giving the location of the image because if the location of the application changes it will not display the image. So I want to know if there is any other way possible?

Edit:

```
jButton1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Address of the image"));
```

I don't want to add this address since it might change the location.

```
if (status.equals("update"))
jButton1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/laptop/Documents/NetbeansProjects/Physics/src/update.png"));
```

This is the code for changing the image update.png from add.png if status is update. I don't want to write it's address since if the location of the jar file changed it won't display image. The project will run offline, so no need for online suggestion

Comment: Put the image in the application jar file itself, and load it using the classloader. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon-java.net.URL-

Comment: I have added the image to the project itself but it is not working either. I will then convert the project into jar file

Comment: We can't tell you why your code isn't working if you don't post your code.

Comment: jButton1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/laptop/Documents/NetbeansProjects/Physics/src/update.png"));

Comment: `I have added the image to the project itself but it is not working either.` - see [How to Use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for code on loading a resource such as an image.

Comment: I meant the code will work only if the jar file exists at that location only

Comment: So, you're absolutely not doing what I suggest to do. Use the classloader to load the icon, with the help of the two methods I linked to. But yes, you need to read some documentation.

Comment: This is unusual but you can acctualy save the image directly in the source code as a string, BASE64 could be more suitable.

Comment: @JBNizet If I will move my dist file to another computer, it might no be placed in C drive only or in the same location

Comment: Which is exactly why I advise you to put the icon in the jar file of your application itself, and to load the icon using the classloader, using the two methods I linked to. But you're not reading, so I'm preaching in the desert.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry, I read that later

Comment: And I provided you with a link to a tutorial with working examples showing how to use those two methods. Why ask a question if you don't take the time to read the suggestions given?

Comment: @camickr I had to go somewhere so I couldn't read your suggestions. So sorry

Answer (score 0):

simply add the image file in the project directory and provide only the name and format of the file
i.e in case of your example: 
`if (status.equals("update"))
jButton1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("update.png"));`